# How to retrieve number of posts for each topic using MySql Join

Tags: mysql, join

I have been trying to implement few MySql Join queries.

I have three tables namely "topics", "posts" and "users" . This is the schema I have for those tables.
[image]

I am trying to get the topic name, topic contents, topic author's user name, topic  creation date and number of posts it has for all topics. As of now, there are 20 entries in the "topics" table and each topic has 5 entries in the "posts" table. So, the posts table have 100 rows.

I have tried the following query and was expecting to get 20 rows from the result set.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , u.user_name
     , DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p') created_at
     , COUNT(p.id) reply_count 
  FROM topics t 
  JOIN users u 
    ON t.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN posts p 
    ON p.topic_id = t.id
```

But, I haven't been able to get the desired output.  I am  getting only  one row  in the output with the "reply_count" being 100 ( I have 100 entries in the "posts" table)

I feel, I am  doing something wrong in the "COUNT(p.id) as reply_count" part of the query. I tried removing that part with something like .. e.g. "p.id as reply_count"

This is what the modified query looks like

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , u.user_name
     , DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p') created_at
     , p.id reply_count 
  FROM topics t 
  JOIN users u 
    ON t.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN posts p 
    ON p.topic_id = t.id
```

That gives me 100 rows in the result which is correct.

Basically, I am stuck in getting the number of posts for each topic. Where did I go wrong? Could you please provide your suggestions?

**Edit** :

Trying to simulate what tables I have and what kind  results I am expecting ----

This is the [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0e90f/15) of what I tried

Expected output-- 5 rows with each row containing topic id, topic name, topic body, topic creator's user_name, topic created_at time and "number of posts for each topic"

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: alright, noted.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to add one more sub-query to get the count of replies on topic separately and then join with main tables, as below.

```
SELECT t.id,t.name, u.user_name, DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p') as created_at,
p.reply_count
FROM topics t 
JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.id 
join (select id,count(topic_id) reply_count from post group by id) p ON p.topic_id = t.id
```

Comment: Didn't work. [Sqlfiddle of your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0e90f/8/0) . Please view my edit

Comment: I replaced "group by id" with group by "topic_id" and it worked now

Answer (score -1):

Trying again:

```
select topics.id, topics.name, topics.body, users.user_name, topics.created_at, post_count.qty
from topics, users, posts,
(select topic_id, count(id) as qty from posts group by posts.topic_id) as post_count
where topics.id = posts.topic_id
and users.id=topics.user_id
and posts.topic_id = post_count.topic_id
group by posts.topic_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Posting this as an answer just in case somebody else finds it helpful

The following queries worked for me, [This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) cleared some confusions. I had to use GROUP BY

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , u.user_name
     , DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p') as created_at
     , p.reply_count 
  FROM topics t  
  JOIN users u 
    ON t.user_id = u.id  
  join (select id
            ,topic_id
            , count(id) reply_count 
         from posts 
       group 
           by topic_id
     ) p 
    ON p.topic_id = t.id;
```

And

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.name
     , u.user_name
     , DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, '%M %e, %Y @ %h:%i %p') as created_at
     , COUNT(p.id) as reply_count 
  FROM topics t 
  JOIN users u 
    ON t.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN posts p 
    ON p.topic_id = t.id 
group by t.id;
```

Comment: You're returning an arbitrary id in your first query's subquery. And an arbitrary user_id in your second. That's not good!

Comment: I don't understand the reason for a downvote!! People can provide their suggestions instead of downvoting for every single thing